# Performance of generic VS non-generic method (array generating function)

Tags: java, performance, generics

I'm trying to improve performance for a generic function that turns a string into a multidimensional array.

Expected input:

- A string that was generated by the function `Arrays.deepToString()`.
- The original array had no null values and did not contain arrays of length 0.
- The array can have any number of dimensions from 1 to 200.
- Sub-arrays may have different length (e.g. `arr[0].length != arr[1].length`)

The function converts the values into the requested data type, which may be any primitive variable or String.

```
private static String[] arraySeparators;
private static Class[] arrayTypes;

public static <T> Object reverseDeepToString(String str, Class<T> dataType){
    int dimensions = 0;
    while(str.charAt(dimensions) == '[')
        dimensions++;

    arraySeparators = new String[dimensions + 1];
    String separator = ", ";
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arraySeparators[x] = separator = ']' + separator + "\\[";

    arrayTypes = new Class[dimensions + 1];
    Class temp = arrayTypes[2] = Array.newInstance(dataType, 0).getClass();
    for(int x = 3; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arrayTypes[x] = temp = Array.newInstance(temp, 0).getClass();

    str = str.substring(dimensions, str.length() - dimensions);
    Object r = createArrayRecursive(str, dimensions, dataType);

    arraySeparators = null;
    arrayTypes = null;
    return r;
}

private static <T> Object createArrayRecursive(String str, int dimension, Class<T> dataType){

    if(dimension == 1){
        String[] s = str.split(", ");
        Object result = Array.newInstance(dataType, s.length);
        for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++){
            if(dataType == String.class) Array.set(result, x, s[x]);
            else if(dataType == int.class) Array.set(result, x, Integer.parseInt(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == double.class) Array.set(result, x, Double.parseDouble(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == float.class) Array.set(result, x, Float.parseFloat(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == long.class) Array.set(result, x, Long.parseLong(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == boolean.class) Array.set(result, x, Boolean.parseBoolean(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == short.class) Array.set(result, x, Short.parseShort(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == byte.class) Array.set(result, x, Byte.parseByte(s[x]));
            else if(dataType == char.class) Array.set(result, x, s[x].charAt(0));
        }
        return result;
    }
    String[] s = str.split(arraySeparators[dimension]);
    Object arr = Array.newInstance(arrayTypes[dimension], s.length);

    for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++)
        Array.set(arr, x, createArrayRecursive(s[x], dimension - 1, dataType));

    return arr;
}
```

The problem is that these workarounds to deal with limitations of generic types are slowing down the function significantly compared to the non-generic equivalent:

```
private static String[] arraySeparators;

public static Object reverseDeepToString(String str){
    int dimensions = 0;
    while(str.charAt(dimensions) == '[')
        dimensions++;
    arraySeparators = new String[dimensions + 1];
    String separator = ", ";
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arraySeparators[x] = separator = ']' + separator + "\\[";
    str = str.substring(dimensions, str.length() - dimensions);
    return createArrayRecursive(str, dimensions);
}

private static Object createArrayRecursive(String str, int dimension){

    if(dimension == 1){
        String[] s = str.split(", ");
        double[] result = new double[s.length];
        for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++)
            result[x] = Double.parseDouble(s[x]);
        return result;
    }
    String[] s = str.split(arraySeparators[dimension]);
    int[] lengths = new int[dimension];
    lengths[0] = s.length;
    Object arr = Array.newInstance(double.class, lengths);

    for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++)
        Array.set(arr, x, createArrayRecursive(s[x], dimension - 1));

    return arr;
}
```

My question is: is there a way to make a generic function as efficient as a non-generic function, or at least get very close to it?

The only alternative I have in mind is creating lots of copies of the non-generic function (one for each variable type), and have a main function choosing which non-generic function to use, but that will be a very long and ugly code that I try to avoid:

```
public static <T> Object reverseDeepToString(String str, Class<T> dataType){

    if(dataType == int.class) return reverseDeepToString_int(str);
    if(dataType == double.class) return reverseDeepToString_double(str);
    if(dataType == long.class) return reverseDeepToString_long(str);
    if(dataType == String.class) return reverseDeepToString_string(str);
    if(dataType == boolean.class) return reverseDeepToString_boolean(str);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(dataType == double.class) Array.set(result, x, Double.parseDouble(s[x]));
```

Using `Array.set()` in the line above was a mistake because it is boxing the primitive types. Using `Array.setInt()`, `Array.setDouble()`, etc improved the performance a lot, but it's still a bit slower than using a non-generic function:

```
if(dataType == double.class) Array.setDouble(result, x, Double.parseDouble(s[x]));
```

The performance can be improved further by casting the array to the needed type:

```
if(dataType == double.class) ((double[])result)[x] = Double.parseDouble(s[x]);
```

Performance test code and results: https://pastebin.com/3g37vDm4

### Improved function:

```
private static String[] arraySeparators;
private static Class[] arrayTypes;

public static <T> Object reverseDeepToString(String str, Class<T> dataType){
    int dimensions = 0;
    while(str.charAt(dimensions) == '[')
        dimensions++;

    arraySeparators = new String[dimensions + 1];
    String separator = ", ";
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arraySeparators[x] = separator = ']' + separator + "\\[";

    arrayTypes = new Class[dimensions + 1];
    Class temp = arrayTypes[1] = dataType;
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arrayTypes[x] = temp = Array.newInstance(temp, 0).getClass();

    str = str.substring(dimensions, str.length() - dimensions);
    Object r = createArrayRecursive(str, dimensions);

    arraySeparators = null;
    arrayTypes = null;
    return r;
}

private static Object createArrayRecursive(String str, int dimension){

    if(dimension == 1){
        String[] s = str.split(", ");
        Class dataType = arrayTypes[1];
        Object result = Array.newInstance(dataType, s.length);
        for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++){
            if(dataType == String.class) ((String[])result)[x] = s[x];
            else if(dataType == int.class) ((int[])result)[x] = Integer.parseInt(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == double.class) ((double[])result)[x] = Double.parseDouble(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == float.class) ((float[])result)[x] = Float.parseFloat(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == long.class) ((long[])result)[x] = Long.parseLong(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == boolean.class) ((boolean[])result)[x] = Boolean.parseBoolean(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == short.class) ((short[])result)[x] = Short.parseShort(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == byte.class) ((byte[])result)[x] = Byte.parseByte(s[x]);
            else if(dataType == char.class) ((char[])result)[x] = s[x].charAt(0);
        }
        return result;
    }
    String[] s = str.split(arraySeparators[dimension]);
    Object arr = Array.newInstance(arrayTypes[dimension], s.length);

    dimension--;
    for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++)
        Array.set(arr, x, createArrayRecursive(s[x], dimension));

    return arr;
}
```

To make the performance perfectly match the non-generic function I can also avoid the casting, but this results in a longer and uglier code for a rather small difference in performance:

```
private static String[] arraySeparators;
private static Class[] arrayTypes;

public static <T> Object reverseDeepToString(String str, Class<T> dataType){
    int dimensions = 0;
    while(str.charAt(dimensions) == '[')
        dimensions++;

    arraySeparators = new String[dimensions + 1];
    String separator = ", ";
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arraySeparators[x] = separator = ']' + separator + "\\[";

    arrayTypes = new Class[dimensions + 1];
    Class temp = arrayTypes[1] = dataType;
    for(int x = 2; x <= dimensions; x++)
        arrayTypes[x] = temp = Array.newInstance(temp, 0).getClass();

    str = str.substring(dimensions, str.length() - dimensions);
    Object r = createArrayRecursive(str, dimensions);

    arraySeparators = null;
    arrayTypes = null;
    return r;
}

private static Object createArrayRecursive(String str, int dimension){

    if(dimension == 1){
        String[] s = str.split(", ");
        Class dataType = arrayTypes[1];

        if(dataType == String.class){
            String[] result = new String[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = s[x];
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == int.class){
            int[] result = new int[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Integer.parseInt(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == double.class){
            double[] result = new double[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Double.parseDouble(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == float.class){
            float[] result = new float[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Float.parseFloat(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == long.class){
            long[] result = new long[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Long.parseLong(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == boolean.class){
            boolean[] result = new boolean[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Boolean.parseBoolean(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == short.class){
            short[] result = new short[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Short.parseShort(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == byte.class){
            byte[] result = new byte[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = Byte.parseByte(s[x]);
            return result;
        }
        if(dataType == char.class){
            char[] result = new char[s.length];
            for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) result[x] = s[x].charAt(0);
            return result;
        }
    }
    String[] s = str.split(arraySeparators[dimension]);
    Object arr = Array.newInstance(arrayTypes[dimension], s.length);

    dimension--;
    for(int x = 0; x < s.length; x++)
        Array.set(arr, x, createArrayRecursive(s[x], dimension));

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You check the type and do cast for every set operation, this isn't performance wise. Instead of this if else chain you could just pass to this method an lamda expression that would handle the set operation to proper type. Also doing the cast of array to a specific type you just avoid the promotion of every primitive to Object, which as I said was the source of the significant performance degradation.

Comment: Also my answer already pointed that the source of your performance degardation was the promotion from primitive types to Object. Casting the array to specific primitive type before the set operation just avoids this promition from happening.

Comment: I think that you misattribute this performance degradation to Array.set() due to test flaw, please show the testing code and test results instead of bare words.

Comment: There you go: https://pastebin.com/JzTJ50Sv

I also made a similar test to compare the speed of the whole generic function VS non-generic function, the results indicate that any difference between them is negligible.

Comment: Array.set takes Object, if you put an int there it gets promoted to Integer in every step of for loop. As I thought you do a promotion from int to Integer, this takes time. This is a flaw in your test. You can try to construct an Integer object before the for loop and then put it to the array using array.set(), such a way you will remove the promotion from happening and the results would be more adequate.

Comment: Thanks for being so keen to help me optimize the code further :) but it's good enough as it is now and I rather keep the code shorter than try to save a few microseconds

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki is correct. The issue in your original code is using `Array.set(....)` for a primitive `double` value. That method boxes the `double` in to a `Double` and then unboxes it again in to a `double`. If you use the primitive method `Array.setDouble(....)` instead, your performance problems will be gone. See [`Array.setDouble(....)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#setDouble(java.lang.Object,int,double)).

Comment: @rolfl It was a mistake indeed, and I tried using `Array.setDouble()` too but it made a very small difference in performance, my final solution vastly outperformed both. Here is the code + results of a performance test comparing `Array.set()`, `Array.setInt()` and my final solution: https://pastebin.com/QA4tyEqw

Comment: @potato - your test methodology looks somewhat broken. I suspect that the constant-value array set is being optimized out.... i.e. you are not actually running the loop 100,000,000 times.... because the Java JIT compiler sees that there's no difference in the results. Benchmarking Java runtime is extremely complicated. I have done this in the past, and getting reliable tests is "really hard". See my github project for the resulting test-suite: https://github.com/rolfl/MicroBench

Comment: @rolfl True, thanks for pointing this out, now I know how to conduct more reliable speed tests, when I tested it properly it was much slower. BUT lucky me - the way I discovered thanks to my ignorance is still faster lol https://pastebin.com/ZeQ7mqvZ

Comment: I edited the answer, now everything should be correct

Answer (score 2):

The only option to have this really fast is to use primitive types, which in turn requires to write "non-generic" (specialised for every primitive type) function (piece of code) for every primitive type that you would like to use. By "non-generic" here I mean code that use specialised types only, without promotion. There is no other option. Conversion from primitives to Object just take time, you can save it using non-generic function.

`Array.set()` is generic because it takes Object as an input, thats why it promotes every primitive to Object.

Comment: Casting takes a negligible amount of time even when repeated billions of times, so it doesn't matter for the optimization.

Comment: Where do i said that it is the cast that causes the performance degradation? I said that conversion from primitives to Object is the source of the performance degradation, not the cast itself, do you know the difference between plain cast and promotion?

Comment: Adding to my answer, the if else chain executed for every set op takes time, you can optimize it either using a lamda in java >=8 or non-generic function for java <8

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. Anyway converting primitive types to Object has a negligible effect on performance. The function Array.set() itself was causing the biggest overhead.

Comment: I think that you misattribute this performance degradation to Array.set() due to test flaw, please show the testing code and test results instead of bare words.

Comment: Ok after resolving all the confusion I understand what you meant, the function `Array.set()` is boxing primitive types, next time please be more specific for the sake of clarity. Also this part is incorrect: "The only option to have this really fast is to use primitive types, which in turn requires to write non-generic function for every primitive type" - I did achieve the performance level of the non-generic function with my generic function.

Comment: Well, since I run out of memory before I can generate an input large enough to make a noticeable difference between the performance of the generic and non-generic functions, I'd say it's close enough. One important thing to know about optimization is when not to worry about it, optimize only what needs to be optimized and only as much as you need to. Copying the same function 9 times just to save a few microseconds is really overkill and just makes the code longer and uglier.

Comment: I think that you're not experienced enough yet to perform this kind of performance testing and because of that most of your assumptions and results in this subject is wrong.

Comment: You are right about me testing performance badly in the beginning, but since then I did some learning and improved my performance test, take a look at this one: https://pastebin.com/3g37vDm4

Comment: Arguing with you is like fighting against myself, everything that you have learned from me you use to defeat what I said to you and prove me wrong. The createArrayRecursive3 is exactly "non-generic", because you have separate for loop for every data type without any casts or promotions. The non-genericity mentioned was about using specilised types instead of intermadiate casts to Object, the extraction of these to separate methods is just good programming practice - It should be extracted to separate private methods for each type separatelly only to make the code clearer. That's all.

Comment: I know that, but I also found with the same test that the difference between it and the other generic function (the one with casting) is negligible, just test the 4 functions yourself and you'll see the performance difference between them... In my program I use the `reverseDeepToString()` function and there are no noticeable performance changes from when I used the `reverseDeepToString_non_generic()`. The only thing that keeps this argument going is you not believing me, so run a performance test yourself to clear all your doubts.